# Unique rows of each Ref Number where

Tags: sql

This is my table:

```
Ref Num     Status  Task Status
TB011       RET     
TB012       RET     
TB013       INP     Ready
TB013       INP     
TB013       INP     
TB014       INP     In Process
TB014       INP     
TB014       INP     
TB015       INP     Completed
TB015       INP     Ready
TB015       INP     
TB016       INP     Ready
TB016       INP     In Process
TB016       INP     
TB017       INP     Completed
TB017       INP     In Process
TB017       INP     Ready
TB017       INP
```

I need to get unique row of each "Ref Num" where:

- if `Status` = `RET` there only going to be one row where `Task Status` will always be null
- if `Status` = `INP` I need only the first row where `Task Status` is not Completed

The result should look like that:

```
Ref Num     Status  Task Status
TB011       RET     
TB012       RET     
TB013       INP     Ready
TB014       INP     In Process
TB015       INP     Ready
TB016       INP     Ready
TB017       INP     In Process
```

Remark! I have many more columns after `Ref Num`, `Status`, `Task Status` with different data and I also need them.

Comment: Use the `code` button to format code blocks. Read: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: Do you have an `id` column to indicate an order?

Comment: Have you tried to anything yet on which we can build?

Comment: I dont have Id column, but I have Task Number column where every next task is bigger and starts from begining for next ref number.

Answer (score 0):

First, SQL tables represent unordered sets.  As such, there is no such thing as a "first" row in a table.  There needs to be another column that specifies the ordering.  Let me assume that you have such a row.  I'll call it `id`.

What you have is a prioritization problem.  Most databases support the ANSI standard `row_number()` function.  You can do what you want with clever use of the `order by` clause in `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by RefNum
                                order by (case when status = 'Ret' and taskstatus is null then 1
                                               when status <> 'Ret' and taskstatus <> 'Completed' then id
                                          end)
                                end) as seqnum
      from mytable t
     ) t;
```

where seqnum = 1;

Answer (score 0):

if you have a primary key then you can use that in clause to filter again.

without the primary key i tried as follow hope it may solve your problem.

SELECT * 
FROM  `test` 
WHERE  `status` =  'RET'
OR  `status` =  "INP"
AND  `task_sta` <>  'Completed'
GROUP BY  `refid` 
LIMIT 0 , 30;